# Convert Text To Bitmap(Pixel) on Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have an android application in which I need to download text from a website, convert it into bitmap format and display it on an LED-based display board.

I am struggling with the bitmap conversion.

Tried to use the following:

```
Bitmap mybitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 16, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
Canvas c = new Canvas(mybitmap);
c.drawText("0", 0, 0, paint);
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions?

**Update:**

Paint object is initialized like this:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setTextSize(16);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
```

Comment: how to you initialize your paint object?

Answer (score 4):

I think you draw outside the image. Try setting y to `16`.

```
c.drawText("0", 0, 16, paint);
```

---

Note that when drawing text the coordinate origin is the lower left coordinate corner.

Comment: True. I found a similar suggestion on another post and tried it. But unfortunately doesn't work.


The bitmap object remains unaffected (height = width= -1) 
`Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(16, 16, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);`

Shouldn't the height and width be 16 as per this code ?

Since I am new to this I don't know if my understanding is messed up or I am missing some config/permissions etc.

Would really appreciate any help or insight on this.

Comment: Ah, try creating your bitmap with ARGB_8888 config instead.

Comment: Things finally worked! :)
`Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(16, 16, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
float x = bm.getWidth();
float y = bm.getHeight();`
Using `getHeight` and `getWidth` initialized the bitmap correctly and then the remaining code worked.

@dacwe: Thank you for all your suggestions.

Comment: How do you then use the canvas in layout? I tried `setContentView(c)`, but it does not allow me to do that.