# How to create a custom notification on Android. Text instead of image

Tags: android

I want to create notification like here:

[image]

Red circle = icon which is always visible. Blue circle = icon that is visible only when you expand.

How do I make such a red circle notification?

must I create 100 images or can I use custom notification like text? Can i join two images together?

I found this:

http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/02/20/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-on-android/

[Custom notification layouts and text colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors)

But I still don't know how to create this red circle. With this i know how to create blue circle but this I don't need. I am not creating battery!

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to use shapes? And so, create the layout with shapes?

Comment: @Neto Marin sharpes? not yet. Do you have any example or howto? Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only text that you can put in the notification area/status bar ("red circle") is ticker text, which disappears after it's displayed (setTicker). The purpose of that area is to remind users that a notification is outstanding, using the small icon (setSmallIcon). You *could* make 100 different icons, one for each percentage, but then you would not be using Android's standard design guidelines for notifications.

I suggest that if you want a battery indicator, use 5 battery icons. One icon would be a "full" battery, along with 1 each for 75%, 50%, 25%, and "very low" (in red). I suspect that most users don't need to see *exactly* how much battery they have left in the status bar. You can then show the exact numbers and estimated time remaining in the full notification.