# custom view instead of notification icon

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-custom-view

I want to show a notification with a **custom view in *notification area***.for example a view include 2 `TextViews`. and texts of this `TextViews` should change every 5 minuts.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom notification using that code:
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/15/create-custom-notification-android-custom-layout/

You can update the Notification, by notify it with the same ID:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating

Comment: thanks. your answer is a way for creating a custom view in notification drawer but I want to create a custom view in notification area.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't understand your question in the beginning. After searching for an answer look what i found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921110/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-on-android-text-instead-of-image - :/